# How can I speed up string concatenation

Tags: python, multithreading

I have about 3000000 strings with HTML tags. I am trying to remove the tags and take the content.I have a code in following way. But it is taking a lot of time. Is there any way I can do parallel processing? Any way I can speed my implementation?

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser  
class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
        def __init__(self):
            self.reset()
            self.fed = []
        def handle_data(self, d):
            self.fed.append(d)
        def get_data(self):
            return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()

for each in lis:
    if each != None:
        each = strip_tags(each)
        st+=" "+each.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: 3Million strings, even if they take 0.1 milli seconds each will easily take 1000 seconds in total...

Comment: It took me half an hour last time. They are some big strings. And 3 million is a sample of the total lot.

Comment: You will need to give the complete code, I am afraid the problem won't  be only with how you join them... That, or time measurements for feed method.

Comment: That is the complete code the lis is a list with strings like <p>hello</p> in it. You can try it it works.

Comment: It is getting extremely slow after 2Lakh. I have a 8 gb RAM.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't feed all the data into single MLStripper instance (rather than creating/destroying many instances of MLStripper) and then extract the results at the end. And do the processing in the MLStripper class (e.g. decode). Can you share an example of the data and the expected output...

Comment: Yes Doing that, It speeded up a bt

Answer (score 2):

Doing string concatenation in a for loop will create problems as a new string object will need to be created for each concatenation (twice for each iteration of the loop in your case).

You can use join and a generator to improve efficiency.

```
for each in lis:
    if each != None:
        each = strip_tags(each)
        st+=" "+each.decode('utf-8')
```

becomes:

```
st = " ".join(strip_tags(each).decode('utf-8') for each in lis if each is not None)
```

Comment: Question asks for multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a multi-core computer that has 8 cores. Use Linux bash command:

```
 split -l 375000 filename
```

This will give you 8 files with 375000 lines each. The filenames will be "xaa", "xab", "xac", ... and "xah". Next, run your program 8 times on the 8 smaller files (use & at the end of each command). The OS should run each of them on a different core in parallel. Then concatenate the 8 output files into one result file.

Answer (score 1):

To further answer your question about parallel processing: yes you could use that here. One idea is to use map and reduce with ipython mutiprocessing, hadoop, AWS' EMR, etc. to strip all those strings and concat them into some file or other output stream.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked the code bellow, but it answers strictly the question of how to process the input in parallel. I think your code could benefit from other optimisations as well, but check the other answers for that.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser  

from multiprocessing import Pool

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
        def __init__(self):
            self.reset()
            self.fed = []
        def handle_data(self, d):
            self.fed.append(d)
        def get_data(self):
            return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    lis=[]#you should get lis contents here

    pool = Pool()

    pool.map(strip_tags, (each for each in lis if each !=None))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```